# Moving data frame to particular X.Y location using real world coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, data-frame

My mxd file has multiple dataframes. How do I move a given dataframe to a particular location within the main dataframe in the layout view to a particular x,y location given by user. The location x,y would dicatate the center of data frame to be moved.

Comment: Are your XY coordinates map coordinates or real world coordinates?

Comment: realworld coordinates

Answer (score 1):

I assume that it is possible to use the Go To XY Tool on the main dataframe in Data View, select Add Point, and then switch to Layout View to get the paper location of the added point by zooming in and hovering the mouse over the point.

You could then use the paper location of the point in the Layout view to center the smaller dataframe, provided that the anchor point of the smaller dataframe is set to the center in the Size and Position tab in the dataframe properties. You can manually enter the paper coordinates also in that tab.

[image: dataframe_properties]